# The correct way to create an index in EF6.2 using HasIndex and model without the foreign key property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I Created this example using EF 6.2 to create an index using the foreign key of the model.

I like to create models without the foreign keys, to make the model cleaner, this way I coudn't create the index.

that's the code:

```
[Table("A")]
public class A
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
[Table("B")]
public class B 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}


public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> A { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> B { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Attempt 1
        modelBuilder.Entity<B>().HasIndex(x => x.A).IsUnique();
        //Attempt 2
        modelBuilder.Entity<B>().HasIndex(x => x.A.Id).IsUnique();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }


}
```

Both attempts went wrong with those errors:

Attempt 1 :

Sequence contains no matching element

Attempt 2:

The properties expression 'x => x.B.Id' is not valid. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: C#: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) New With { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.

Comment: "I like to create models without the foreign keys, to make the model cleaner"  Well this is one of the many reasons you shouldn't do that.  You could probably get this to work in EF Core, which will expose the Foreign Key using a Shadow Property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties

Comment: I know that EF 4 to 6 have issues with models without FK, but I managed to overcome all of those issues, but I don't have another way to create the index, if there were an extension method  like this .HasIndex(new string[]{"A_Id"}).IsUnique() would solve this

Comment: You can always use custom SQL in a migration, or a Database-First design workflow. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx  Note that you will want to _drop_ the index that supports the FK and replace it with a unique index.